# Store hundreds of versions on a server : what compression to use?

Tags: php, serialization, version-control, compression, versioning

For an online text editor project I'm building, the *saving* of projects is similar to what does http://jsfiddle.net :

- the first version is `sdf23f`,
- the second `Save` leads to `sdf23f/1`, the third `Save` leads to `sdf23f/2`, etc.

When someone hits `Save`, a PHP file is called which saves the data into server :

```
<?php if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
$data = $_POST['data'];
$fname = $_POST['id'];
$file = fopen("data/" . $fname, 'w');
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Then there will be hundreds of versions (i.e. hundreds of similar files) in the same folder.

**At which stage should compression be done, in order to save server storage ?** 
**What kind of compression ?** Inside PHP, or should compression be hanlded by something else ?

Comment: Why don't you save to a database instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At which stage should compression be done, in order to save server storage ?

Erm ... before you save the files.

> Inside PHP, or should compression be hanlded by something else ?

I'm sure you could implement suitable "compression" inside PHP ... if you knew what you are doing.  But there are also existing utilities for doing this kind of thing (certainly on Linux / Unix ...)

But I think what you really need to know is what kind of "compression" technique to use. And the answer is that the way to save space when storing multiple versions of a text file is (typically) to store the *differences* between the successive versions, rather than full versions. So you might store:

- The complete latest version (say version N).
- Differences from version N to version N -  1
- Differences from version N -1 to version N - 2.
- and so on.

It is then possible to compress (in the conventional sense) the base file and the differences, though if the difference files are small they won't be very compressible.

The other thing you need to do to space (on a typical file system) is to not to store lots of individual small files.  A typical file system allocates disk space in blocks of a few kilobytes.  If you files are small, you end up wasting a significant proportion of the last disk block in each file.  That can be significant.

The standard way to deal that is to use an "archive" format (like tar or zip) that can hold multiple "files" in a single archive.  You can then compress the archive to save further space.  (Though compressing files that are already compressed won't help ...)

---

@Rasclatt commented:

> Why don't you save to a database instead?

Well:

- Using a database doesn't directly address the space usage issue *per se*.  (Unless the database has compression support.)
- You then have to access the files via the database ... which is typically slower than if you read them directly from the file system.